# How do I set WordPress to send 2 different emails based on criteria in the database when someone submits a form?

Tags: plugins, database, email

I'm trying to create a small program registration system that allows users to register for a course AFTER carrying out an Advisory session with a lecturer.

The database will contain a table with the student's details (Name, contact, etc) and a column called "Attended_Advisory" with Yes or No being the criteria.

If someone submits a registration form with a name that is already in the system with "Yes" under the Advisory column, I want the system to send them an email with further instructions and info.

If their name does not exist in the database, it will add their details to the database and then list "No" under the Advisory column, and in that case, I want the system to send them an email informing them that they must attend the advisory session first.

How do I go about setting up something like that where "Yes" or "No" in that column will send different emails?

Comment: It would help if you included the code that records this info or the registration so that we could show you where to inject the conditional check.

Comment: do you have the form already? There's no code in your question to extend/modify. Are you using a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do, assuming I understand correctly, is check if the user already exists in the system.  I don't think using names is a good idea, two people can have identical names.  I have two guys with the same first and last name that play on a soccer team with me.  Emails are at least unique, so I'd check that.

Once you determine if the person already exists or not and I guess then you'd update their the `Attended_Advisory` column to 'Yes' or `true` or `1`.  (I use `1` and `0` for `true` and `false` just to keep things as lean as possible.)

Then, when the registration is complete you retrieve the data from the custom table and add the `Attended_Advisory` value to a variable.

`$attended_advisory = the_result_of_the_db_query; //query that retrieves the attended advisory value from the custom table`

Next you run a conditional check on that value, something like:

```
if( empty( $attended_advisory ) || $attended_advisory === 'No' ) :
     /*Send the Email for NO */
     /*This condition checks if the value IS empty OR if it is a No */ 
else :
    /*Send the Email for YES */
    /*This condition checks if the value IS NOT empty AND if it is a Yes */
endif;
```

You could even add a layer as a just in case:

```
if( empty( $attended_advisory ) || $attended_advisory === 'No' ) :
   /*Send the Email for NO */
   /*This condition checks if the value IS empty OR if it is a No */
elseif( !empty( $attended_advisory ) && $attended_advisory === 'Yes' ) :
   /*Send the Email for YES
   /*This condition checks if the value IS NOT empty AND if it is a Yes */
else :
   /*Send the Email for NO - a fallback that covers everything else. */
endif;
```

That's the logic. You'll obviously have to modify the above to work with how you have things set up above, but logically this is the process.